# jQuery Rotator Is Alphabetical, how can I make it randomized on my homepage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotator

How can I get images to be random on my rotator? Below is a link to the site I am working on and the rotator on the homepage is currently displaying alphabetically and I would like it random.

http://www.greatrestaurantsmagazine.com/

Comment: If you can help please explain with great detail as I am brand new to script

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like moving the list to a document fragment and then adding them back one by one using a randomizer while checking that the items it attempts to add back haven't been added yet.

Comment: huh? I am a beginner don't eve know where to start with that answer??? How ? where ? Thanks but I have no idea how to go about doiong that

Answer (score 0):

Open up your disolve.js and make the below changes.

key here is randomizing your next image , apparently the code below :

You can download a small demo [here](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/downloads/image-rotator.zip)

Make sure you follow [these](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator.html) intstructions in the code

```
//Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order

var sibs = current.siblings();
var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );                      
var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );

And then below your document ready section will look like:

$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    $('div.rotator ul').shuffle();
    theRotator();
    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not an interactive debug session.